# What are the benefits of Pact testing other than contract verifying?

Tags: testing, jestjs, integration-testing, pact, e2e

I want to know this pact testing in more details. I know by pact testing we can verify request and response and mostly it is consumer driven. Are there any more benefits other than this. If yes, can someone help me to understand this in details?

Comment: I found it to be pretty useless to be honest as whenever API X has some changes you won't know it until e2e start crashing, or worse, production crashes

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the principal benefit is to have in sync between the providers and consumers, this way you can automatically detect when a change breaks the contract and then don't deploy it to avoid issues in the consumer side.

When pack is installed and configured, writing tests is not so difficult, and is a plus layer of security for your app...

Answer (score -1):

One of the biggest benefits is that you can reduce the amount of integration testing that you need to do, without increasing the risk of bugs.

Here are some of the benefits: https://docs.pact.io/faq/convinceme